# How to call a php variable (not from a entity class) into a twig file

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i want to call a php variable into a twig file.

suppose in my function i am getting "$usrname", so how can i return the value in the twig file ---

```
public function helloTestAction(){
    $usrname = $user->getUserDetails()->get()->getLatestName();
    // UserDetails is the entity class name
.........
}
```

**Suppose i get the answer "Hello Test", so now how can i return this value into my twig file.**

So how can i get the "$usrname" in my twig file.

Anyone knows any solution for this problem. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: what does it return? or what error message is shown?

Comment: @Rocky thanks for your answer, but i need to return this value in the twig file not in a php class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as below :

```
return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index.html.twig', array(
            'usrname' => $usrname
    ));
```